# SVG backend for gloss?

Tags: haskell, gloss

I am using gloss http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss for very simple (static) pictures, using lines, and some scaling/translation. How could I output them in the SVG format?

Comment: how simple? Are you using the gloss `display`, `animate`, `simulate`, or `play`? Can you post an example? One thought would be to map your picture elements to `Diagrams` objects, as `Diagrams` has an SVG backend.

Comment: nice, I wasn't aware of this. (For reference, http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/ )